# Why are my graphics not appearing on the panel c#

Tags: c#, forms, panel

The code displayed below is used for drawing different shapes, the problem that i am facing is that when i use the same code to display the drawings on the windows form it displays,,,but when i try to display them on a panel..it shows as blank during runtime..please have a look at the code and tell me where i am going wrong. Thank in advance to whoever replies to this post!

```
    private ArrayList ds;
    private Point mold;
    private Point mcurr;
    private int mshape;
    private float mwidth;
    private Color mcolor;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ds = new ArrayList();
        mshape = 0;
        //mwidth = 1;
        //mcolor = Color.Black;
        DoubleBuffered = true; 

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 9);
        richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    }


    private Rectangle rec(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        Rectangle a = new Rectangle();
        a.X = (p1.X > p2.X ? p2.X : p1.X);
        a.Y = (p1.Y > p2.Y ? p2.Y : p1.Y);
        a.Width = Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X);
        a.Height = Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y);
        return a;
    }


    private void draw(Graphics e, Point mold, Point mcur, int mshape, float mwidth, Color mcolor)
    {
       Pen p = new Pen(mcolor, mwidth);

        switch (mshape)
        {
            case 0:
                e.DrawRectangle(p, rec(mold, mcur));

                break;
            case 1:
                e.DrawEllipse(p, rec(mold, mcur));
                break;
            case 2:
                e.DrawLine(p, mold, mcur);
                break;
            case 3:
                //this.Invalidate();
                 break;


        }
    }

    private void toolStripButtonRectangle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mshape = 0;
    }

    private void toolStripButtonEllipse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mshape = 1;
    }

    private void toolStripButtonLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mshape = 2;
    }


      private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.mold = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        Class1 a = new Class1(mold, mcur, mshape, mwidth, mcolor);/// create a class
        ds.Add(a);
    }


    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mcur = e.Location;
            Invalidate();

        }

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (Class1 a in ds)
        {
            draw(e.Graphics, a.old, a.cur, a.shape, a.width, a.color);
        }
        draw(e.Graphics, mold, mcur, mshape, mwidth, mcolor);

    }

    private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Graphics erase = panel1.CreateGraphics();
           erase.Clear(panel1.BackColor);

       // g1.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please fix the code example so that it contains only the bare minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In the meantime, you should eliminate the `btn_Clear_Click()` method (the way to "erase" a control is to discard the data representing objects to draw in the control, and then call `Invalidate()` on the control to force it to redraw), and double-check that you have in fact subscribed `panel1_Paint()` to the `panel1`'s `Paint` event.

Comment: Do set the color somewhere!

Comment: Set breakpoint to `panel1_Paint` and to `draw` to see if you hits them and with which params! The default of an unassigned Color is (0,0,0,0) i.e. Transparent!

Comment: @TaW okay will try and get back to you

Comment: @TaW i can see the shape during debugging mode but during runtime it doesnt show :/

Comment: That sounds as if you are clearing it after drawing; can't see where it happens from here..Where do you set the color?

Comment: i do it in the  paint event

Comment: I don't see that. Anything funny in Class1? Do put a breakpoint to the `erase.Clear(panel1.BackColor);` line to make sure you don't accidentally hit it..